# Fixed size SVD and solver in CUDA (in the device)

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, gpgpu, eigen

I implemented a program on the GPU (CUDA)  which only uses the host (in C++) to start new kernels. During the calculation on the device I need **SVD** and **solving systems** of 3x3 (dense) matrices, fixed size.

I've got my own SVD and solver implementation but it is not numerical stable (thus not usable). Due to me being rather new with C++ and CUDA I would prefer to use a library instead. (numerical stuff is very tricky)

Now I have trouble finding that library:

- cuSOLVER is not callable from the device
- cuLA is not callable form the device (and abandoned so it seems)
- Eigen looks promising (should be callable from device?) but it is unclear what the status is on CUDA support (it says experimental). I find people saying it works, others got compile errors?

Preferable I would also being able to do general matrix operations with the library (transpose, inversion, sum, multiply, ...) as my own implementations will likely be less efficient and numerically stable for those.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
Seems like Eigen supports basic functions like *,+, transpose and even eigenvalues but SVD, inverse ect is not yet supported. This is at the time of writing.

Comment: For a 3x3 matrix, why don't you work out an analytical solution?

Comment: Source code (BSD license) for a batched solver for small fixed-sized matrices is available as a free download from the CUDA registered developer website. It should be easy to use or adapt for your purposes.

Comment: @JackOLantern: i did that but i'm not pleased with the results (numerical issues)

Comment: @njuffa: thanks for the info i might take a look at it if Eigen turns out to be not usable

Comment: @iami I'm very surprised that a numerical solution is more accurate than an analytical one.

Comment: Solving linear systems can be tricky with bad conditioned matrices, my expertise is limited so i prefer a trusted library instead. Although it seems there is currently non available.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [website](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3#Experimental_CUDA_support), a subset of features works for fixed size matrices (3x3 in your case) from Eigen 3.3. The current stable release is 3.2.6 while 3.3 is in alpha. I don't know if specifically SVD is supported in CUDA. I would recommend trying a small MCVE to see if it works (as well as the other functions you require), and if so, implementing it in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately it turned out the subset of usable function in CUDA is very small: transpose, SVD, solving a system, inverse, ... does not seem to be supported on the "__device__" at the time of writing. Resulting in "calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed" errors

Comment: @iami Are you sure you were using version 3.3 and not 3.2.6? I don't know that it works, just trying to help find out.

Comment: Yes, i even tried the current master branch. It still might be something on my end (first time using Eigen). Will do some further testing to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem; want to generate random vectors within a kernel function which requires performing cholesky/eigenvalue decompositions of NxN (N<=5) covariance matrices. Since, as you noted, the MAGMA and CULA libraries are not available from the device, and there seems to be [no cuSOLVER device API yet](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/817782/cusolver-device-api-so-that-i-can-call-from-kernel-/), I've resorted to implementing these myself following algorithms outlined in, for example, Numerical Recipes in C. As for solving linear systems, I'd suggest checking out the cuBLAS (level 2 functions), as it provides some basic functionality. If you want to invert matrices, I'd suggest [cublasmatinvBatched()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-matinvbatched). I haven't used it myself, will give it a try during the weekend, but from the description it sounds promising. Hope others will chime into this thread with better solutions...

Comment: I'm currently working on a MCVE with Eigen as suggested by Avi Ginsburg. So far it seems to compile and work, but i haven't implemented everything yet. Although not everything is supported on the GPU (yet?), you might want to make a MCVE and see if you can get it done.

Comment: In the 3.3 changelog it says that "only a subset of features are supported", but did not find further info. Did you find any specific documentation or are you just going through the source?

Comment: I didn't find anything more specific than "only a subset of features are supported" either, so i'm going through the source but without much progress to be honest (fairly new to C++).

Comment: ok, I'm working on some cuBLAS stuff, I'll post anything that may be of interest.

Comment: I couldn't get cuBLAS to work on my MBP, turns out you need compute capability of at least 3.5 for the device API to work, I got only 3.0. So much for that...Any progress on Eigen? I finished coding up the matrix inverse, eigen/cholesky decompositions following Numerical Recipes in C. Will use these for now...seems so silly having to waste time implementing such basic functionality.

Comment: No, i have contacted the developer for clarification on whether or not these things are implemented (eg i can see #ifdef __cudacc__ in JacobiSVD.h for example). It might be just bugs of course, as the Eigen 3.3-alpha will not compile you have to use the current master branch. I will report back.

Comment: That's great, let's see that they have to say!

Comment: In case you didn't know, this is the official Eigen forum: https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=74 but unfortunately the registration is bugged (and i have no kde.org account) so i can't ask it there (i can image he is too busy to answer emails)

Comment: Haven't heard back from the dev, i assume he won't answer back (i don't blame him). I will work with my own implementation for now.